# Laravel, not using a foreach for relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I want to show all Products and their first image as a thumbnail.

Tables:
-- Products
-- Images (Foreign Key -> id of Products)

In my product list (foeached trough) I want to show the thumbnail of the first image for that product, I'm doing it like this:

```
@foreach($product->images as $image)
    @if($loop->first)
        <img src="{{ $image->thumbnail }}" alt="">
    @endif
@endforeach
```

But this method is ugly and not the best right? What could I do there?

Answer (score 1):

$product->images is a collection so do:

```
if (!$product->images->isEmpty())
    $product->images->first()->thumbnail
```

see the docs for [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-first)

> you may call the first method with no arguments to get the first
>   element in the collection

Comment: Hm, I get `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: hmm could be that the collection is empty so no thumbnail?

Comment: No, there is a thumbnail for that specific product.

Comment: This works, but that makes no sense...? Because the image is not empty, so it should be displayed without the if...?

Comment: you need to debug maybe you use this code in multiple places and in one of them its empty, or maybe post you full code that I can see what are you doing

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's help you:

```
<img src="{!! $product->images()->first()->thumbnail !!}" alt="">
```